# How to run protractor e2e test without opening the browser via Jenkins server?

Tags: browser, jenkins, protractor, angularjs-e2e

1. We are integrated the mercurial repository with Jenkins server.
2. Whenever the repository gets updated, the Jenkins server triggered auto build and run E2E test cases automatically. It launch the browser to run the test cases.
3. So, In my case the Jenkins running on server machine there is no browsers installed. therefore we need to run the protractor E2E test without opening the browser.

Thanks in advance. 
Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need a selenium server - either your own (in this case you would need to fire up selenium nodes), or a third-party service, like [`browserstack`](http://www.browserstack.com/), or [`saucelabs`](https://saucelabs.com/).

Personally, I had experience configuring `Bamboo` to run e2e tests on browserstack on a daily basis. Here is the protractor configuration we were using:

```
'use strict';

var browserstackUser = 'user';
var browserstackKey = 'key';

exports.config = {
    multiCapabilities: [
        {
            'browserstack.user': browserstackUser,
            'browserstack.key': browserstackKey,
            'browserstack.local': 'true',
            'browserstack.debug': 'true',

            'browserName': 'Chrome',
            'os': 'Windows',
            'os_version': '8',

            specs: [
                '*.spec.js'
            ],
            exclude: [
                'footer.disabledCookies.spec.js',
                'footer.disabledFlash.spec.js'
            ]
        },

        {
            'browserstack.user': browserstackUser,
            'browserstack.key': browserstackKey,
            'browserstack.local': 'true',
            'browserstack.debug': 'true',

            'browserName': 'Internet Explorer',
            'browser_version': '9.0',
            'os': 'Windows',
            'os_version': '7',
            'resolution': '1024x768',

            specs: [
                '*.spec.js'
            ],
            exclude: [
                'footer.disabledCookies.spec.js',
                'footer.disabledFlash.spec.js'
            ]
        }
    ],

    maxSessions: 2,

    // Browserstack's selenium server address
    seleniumAddress: 'http://hub.browserstack.com/wd/hub',

    framework: 'jasmine',

    allScriptsTimeout: 300000,

    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:9001',

    onPrepare: function () {
        require('jasmine-reporters');
        var capsPromise = browser.getCapabilities();
        capsPromise.then(function (caps) {
            var browserName = caps.caps_.browserName.toUpperCase();
            var browserVersion = caps.caps_.version;
            var prePendStr = browserName + "-" + browserVersion + "-";
            jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new
                jasmine.JUnitXmlReporter("test-results", true, true, prePendStr));
        });
    },

    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        isVerbose: true,
        includeStackTrace: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 3600000
    }
};
```

Note the use of `JUnitXmlReporter` from [`jasmine-reporters`](https://github.com/larrymyers/jasmine-reporters) which reports test results to a file in `JUnit XML` format. You can postprocess it to show the test results in jenkins.